# Spark Scala year/month function error: not found

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm getting the following error with my code, can you tell me why?

> notebook:28: error: not found: value month
>   retail_df = retail_df.withColumn("Month", month(retail_df("Date")))
>
> notebook:29: error: not found: value year
>   retail_df = retail_df.withColumn("Year", year(retail_df("Date")))

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

// Make cutom schema
var schema = StructType(Array(
       StructField("Store", IntegerType, true),
       StructField("DayOfWeek", IntegerType, true),
       StructField("Date", DateType, true),
       StructField("Sales", IntegerType, true),
       StructField("Customers", IntegerType, true),
       StructField("Open", IntegerType, true),
       StructField("Promo", IntegerType, true),
       StructField("StateHoliday", StringType, true),
       StructField("SchoolHoliday", StringType, true)))

val retail_dfr = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").schema(schema)
var retail_df = retail_dfr.load("/FileStore/tables/Rossman/train.csv")

val sales_custs_df = retail_df.select( "Store", "Sales", "Customers" )
val retails_open_df = retail_df.where( retail_df("Open") > 0)
val holidays_df = retail_df.filter(($"StateHoliday" === 1) && ($"SchoolHoliday" === 1))
val store_ids = retail_df.select(retail_df("Store")).distinct()
var weekday_promos = retail_df.stat.crosstab( "DayOfWeek" , "Promo" )

weekday_promos = weekday_promos.withColumnRenamed( "DayOfWeek_Promo", "DayOfWeek" )
                             .withColumnRenamed( "0", "NoPromo" )
                             .withColumnRenamed( "1","Promo" )

retail_df = retail_df.withColumn("Month", month(retail_df("Date")))
retail_df = retail_df.withColumn("Year", year(retail_df("Date")))

retail_df.show(5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `month` and `year` needs to be imported to use. To import them use

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{month, year}
```

or

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

to import all avaiable sql functions. More information on what's available can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html).

Comment: Bonjour,

J'ai bien fais "import org.apache.spark.sql.function._". Les focntions hour et next_day fonctionnent bien mais pour dayofweek j'ai une erreur.... " error: not found: value dayofweek"..... Pourtant dayofweek apparait bien dans la doc...

Comment: @Anneso: I'm not sure why you'd think I understand French but the `dayofweek` function was added in version 2.3.0. I'm guessing you use an older version than that.

Comment: Sorry I was tired yesturday so I respond in my mother language without thinking ^^. But I am impressed that you understand it ;-). Thank you for your answer!!!! :-)

Comment: @Anneso: No problems, happy to help :)